# segmentation fault using nested vectors

Tags: c++, vector, random

I stumbled upon the following code segment somewhere to create a list of random numbers in a certain interval:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
struct gen_rand_pos{
  double factor;
  public:
    gen_rand_pos(double r=1.0): factor(r/RAND_MAX)
    {}
    double operator()(){
        return rand()*factor;
    }
};

int main(){
  int N = 5;
  std::vector<double> result(N);
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), N, gen_rand_pos(1.0));
  std::cout << result[0] << std::endl;
}
```

It works perfectly fine. I tried to take this one step further and do the same, but this time creating a list(vector) of random unit vectors, uniformly distributed on the sphere. Here is my go at this:

```
double l2_norm(std::vector<double> const& u) {
    double accum = 0.;
    for (double x : u) {
        accum += x * x;
    }
    return sqrt(accum);
}

struct gen_rand_vec{
  double factor;
  public:
    gen_rand_vec(): factor(2.0/RAND_MAX)
    {}
  std::vector<double> operator()(){
    std::vector<double> result = {rand()*factor-1,rand()*factor-1,rand()*factor-1}; // uniform in each component
    double norm = l2_norm(result);
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(),
           std::bind1st(std::multiplies<float>(),1/norm)); // normalize the vector
    return result;
  }
};
```

However if I now try to construct it in the same manner:

```
int main(){
  int N = 5;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> result2(N);
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result2), N, gen_rand_vec());
  std::cout << result2[0][0] <<std::endl;
}
```

I get a segmentation error. Is the problem lying in the back_inserter or am I doing something completely wrong? I can't figure out. I checked the construction of the single vectors and they work just fine, so the mistake has to lie somewhere after that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So when you got your seg fault with your debugger attached; did it say you were in `gen_rand_vec2` or somewhere else?

Comment: @UKMonkey The seg fault only arises whenever I try to access something in result2.
The output is literally: "/var/folders/m9/hfc_39tj5dsfczwmpz42zbrh0000gn/T/test2 ; exit;
0
Segmentation fault: 11" and nothing else :/

Comment: to whoever downvoted: I am happy to hear constructive criticism and change the question.

Comment: Not downvoter; but most debugging requests get downvoted because you need to use your debugger.  Saying what it prints is not debugging.  This might help https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks for the information, I will have a look at this. I'm currently using atom to write C++ and there's not really a debugging feature, also the outputs of errors are not really helpful. Maybe I should use something different (I'm on Mac, that's why I'm not using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default size of inner vectors for `result2` for indices `<0,4>` is 0, so you cannot access

```
result2[0][0]   // inner vector doesn't keep any elements
```

when you call `generate_n` with `back_inserter`, you add new vectors to the end of `result2`. In this case you can access indices of inner vector for `result2[>=5]`.

Comment: So I just had to initialize with length 0 here? oh.. Thank you.

Comment: after calling generate_n you have result2 with 10 elements, for first 5, all inner vectors are empty.

Comment: I'm just confused why this doesn't happen in the first case, is it due to the variable length of vectors? Would I have had this problem if the vector contained a different type of fixed size? like Eigens 3d vector?

Comment: @bernhard_e First example works, and `result` vector has 10 elements too. After `std::vector<double> result(N);` result has 5 elements so you can access `result[0]` - this element exists (you read value of double type, not element of vector as in second example), when you call `generate_n`, size of `result` will be 10.

Comment: That explains everything, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple, [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) is inserting new vectors at the end of `result2`. Hence, you cannot access the first element, since it is not initialized. To solve this, just remove the `(N)` from the initialization of `result2`. [Example](https://repl.it/repls/ScentedPaleCygnet).